# Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in equal to operation

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, inner-join, temp

I'm truly stumped here. I'm getting the title'd error message when I run the **--join--** part of the following query:

```
---Create temp table to hold data---
CREATE TABLE #Address(

[LINE1] nvarchar(256),
[CONTACTID] nvarchar(256),
[COMPANYNAME] nvarchar(256))

GO

INSERT INTO #Address
SELECT DISTINCT ([LINE1]), [CONTACTID], [COMPANYNAME] 

FROM [TBL_CONTACT]
WHERE [LINE1] IS NOT NULL

GO

ALTER TABLE #Address
ADD [AddressID] int identity(1000,1)

GO

--join--
UPDATE [TBL_CONTACT]
SET [TBL_CONTACT].[PrimaryID] = #ADDRESS.[AddressID]
FROM #ADDRESS 
INNER JOIN [TBL_CONTACT]
ON [TBL_CONTACT].[LINE1] = #ADDRESS.[LINE1]
```

I've done something similar in the past (mainly just different column names and different table names) without error so I'm not sure what the problem is here. Its worth noting that I am working with a completely different database than before though.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server?

Comment: I apologize.  Yes. I am using SQL Server 2008r2.

Comment: I was able to get around this by just NOT using a #temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Set the collation on the create for the column

[CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #Address(

[LINE1] nvarchar(256) COLLATE sameAsTBL_CONTACT,
[CONTACTID] nvarchar(256),
[COMPANYNAME] nvarchar(256))

GO
```